# Listing all versioned files and untracked files in git

Tags: git

How can I get the list of all versioned files (committed, cached, modified...)
and untracked files, so excluding only ignored files ?

I tried using different options of `git ls-files`, but can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Following command seems to give what I wanted :

```
git ls-files -c -o --exclude-standard
```